# How to eliminate the flicker on the right edge of TPaintBox (for example when resizing)

Tags: delphi, flicker, doublebuffered, tpanel, paintbox

**Summarization:**
Say that I have a TForm and two panels. The panels are aligned alTop and alClient. The alClient panel contains a TPaintBox, whose OnPaint involve drawing codes.

The default value of DoubleBuffered on the components are false.

During the drawing process, flicker is obvious because the form, the panels all paint their background.

Because the form is covered by the panels, it is probably fine to intercept its WM_ERASEBKGND message. If not, one could see flickering on the panels, and flickering on the right edge of the panels when the form is resized, because form paints its background.

Secondly, because the alTop panel is intended to be a container for some buttons, it is probably fine to set its DoubleBuffered to true to let Delphi ensure there is no flicker on it. It probably won't introduce much performance burden.

Thirdly, because the alClient panel is intended only to be a container for another drawing component, this panel is most likely **not** involved in composing the final drawing. In this respect, it's probably good to use a TPanel descendant instead of a standard TPanel. In this TPanel descendant, override the protected procedure Paint and do nothing inside the procedure, especially not the inherited call to avoid the FillRect call in the base class TCustomPanel.Paint. Furthermore, intercept the WM_ERASEBKGND message and also do nothing inside. This is because when the TPanel.ParentBackground is False, Delphi is responsible for repainting the background, and when it is True, ThemeService is responsible.

Lastly, to paint without flicker in the TPaintBox:
(1) Using VCL built-in drawing routines, it is probably better that...
(2) Using OpenGL, with OpenGL's double buffer enabled.
(3) ...

**===Q: How to eliminate the flicker on the right edge of TPaintBox?===**

Suppose that for one TForm, I have two panels on it. The top one is aligned alTop relative to the form and considered as a container for buttons. The other one is aligned alClient relative to the form and considered as a container for drawing components (such as TPaintBox from VCL, or TPaintBox32 from Graphics32). For the latter panel, its WM_ERASEBKGND message is intercepted.

Now, I use a TPaintBox instance in the following sample code. In its OnPaint handler, I have two choices to draw a drawing that I would expect to be flicker-free. Choice 1 is drawing after filling the rect. Because its parent panel should not erase the background, the drawing should be flicker-free. Choice 2 is drawing onto a TBitmap, whose Canvas is then copied back to the paintbox.

However, both choices are flickering, and the 2nd choice is especially flickering. My main concern is regarding choice 1. If you resize the form, you could see the main part of the flickering occurs on the right edge. Why does this happen? Could some one help to comment on the reason and possible solution? (Note, if I use TPaintBox32 instead of TPaintBox here, the right edge will not flicker at all.)

My secondary concern is that when using choice 1, the minor part of the flickering occurs on the paintbox randomly. It is not very obvious but still observable if you rapidly resize the form. Furthermore, when using choice 2, this kind of flickering becomes much more severe. I didn't find the reason of this. Could some one help to comment on the possible reason and solution?

Any suggestion is appreciated!!

```
    unit uMainForm;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      ExtCtrls, Dialogs;

    type
      TMainForm = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        FPnlCtrl, FPnlScene: TPanel;
        FPbScene: TPaintBox;

        OldPnlWndProc: TWndMethod;

        procedure PnlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
        procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      MainForm: TMainForm;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.Color := clYellow;
      Self.DoubleBuffered := False;

      FPnlCtrl := TPanel.Create(Self);
      FPnlCtrl.Parent := Self;
      FPnlCtrl.Align := alTop;
      FPnlCtrl.Color := clPurple;
      FPnlCtrl.ParentColor := False;
      FPnlCtrl.ParentBackground := False;
      FPnlCtrl.FullRepaint := False;
      FPnlCtrl.DoubleBuffered := False;

      FPnlScene := TPanel.Create(Self);
      FPnlScene.Parent := Self;
      FPnlScene.Align := alClient;
      FPnlScene.Color := clBlue;
      FPnlScene.ParentColor := False;
      FPnlScene.ParentBackground := False;
      FPnlScene.FullRepaint := False;
      FPnlScene.DoubleBuffered := False;

      FPbScene := TPaintBox.Create(Self);
      FPbScene.Parent := FPnlScene;
      FPbScene.Align := alClient;
      FPbScene.Color := clRed;
      FPbScene.ParentColor := False;

      //
      OldPnlWndProc := Self.FPnlScene.WindowProc;
      Self.FPnlScene.WindowProc := Self.PnlWndProc;

      FPbScene.OnPaint := Self.OnScenePaint;

    end;

    procedure TMainForm.PnlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    begin
      if (Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND) then
        Message.Result := 1
      else
        OldPnlWndProc(Message);
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
    var
      tmpSceneBMP: TBitmap;
    begin
      // Choice 1
       FPbScene.Canvas.FillRect(FPbScene.ClientRect);
       FPbScene.Canvas.Ellipse(50, 50, 150, 150);

      // Choice 2
    //  tmpSceneBMP := TBitmap.Create;
    //  tmpSceneBMP.Width := FPbScene.ClientWidth;
    //  tmpSceneBMP.Height := FPbScene.ClientHeight;
    //  tmpSceneBMP.Canvas.Brush.Color := FPbScene.Color;
    //  tmpSceneBMP.Canvas.FillRect(FPbScene.ClientRect);
    //  tmpSceneBMP.Canvas.Ellipse(50, 50, 150, 150);
    //  FPbScene.Canvas.CopyRect(FPbScene.ClientRect, tmpSceneBMP.Canvas,
    //    FPbScene.ClientRect);

    end;

    end.
```

**===Q: How to intercept the panel's repainting its background correctly? ===**
(If I should ask this in a separate question, just say so and I will delete this.)

New a VCL application, pasting the sample code in, attach the FormCreate, run debug. Now hover the mouse over the form, you could see the panel is clearly repainting its background. However, as shown in the sample code, I should already intercepted this behaviour by intercepting the WM_ERASEBKGND message.

Note, if I comment out this three lines,

```
FPnlScene.Color := clBlue;
FPnlScene.ParentColor := False;
FPnlScene.ParentBackground := False;
```

then the WM_ERASEBKGND message can be captured. I have no clue about this difference.

Could some one help to comment on the reason of this behavior, and how to intercept WM_ERASEBKGND message correctly (when ParentBackground := False)?

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      ExtCtrls, Dialogs;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        FPnlScene: TPanel;
        FPbScene: TPaintBox;

        FOldPnlWndProc: TWndMethod;

        procedure PnlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);

        procedure OnSceneMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
          X, Y: Integer);
        procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.Color := clYellow;
      Self.DoubleBuffered := False;

      FPnlScene := TPanel.Create(Self);
      FPnlScene.Parent := Self;
      FPnlScene.Align := alClient;
      FPnlScene.Color := clBlue;
      FPnlScene.ParentColor := False;
      FPnlScene.ParentBackground := False;
      FPnlScene.FullRepaint := False;
      FPnlScene.DoubleBuffered := False;

      FPbScene := TPaintBox.Create(Self);
      FPbScene.Parent := FPnlScene;
      FPbScene.Align := alClient;
      FPbScene.Color := clRed;
      FPbScene.ParentColor := False;

      //
      FOldPnlWndProc := Self.FPnlScene.WindowProc;
      Self.FPnlScene.WindowProc := Self.PnlWndProc;

      Self.FPbScene.OnMouseMove := Self.OnSceneMouseMove;
      Self.FPbScene.OnPaint := Self.OnScenePaint;

    end;

    procedure TForm1.PnlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    begin
      if Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
      begin
        OutputDebugStringW('WM_ERASEBKGND');
        Message.Result := 1;
      end
      else
        FOldPnlWndProc(Message);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnSceneMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    begin
      FPbScene.Repaint;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      FPbScene.Canvas.FillRect(FPbScene.ClientRect);
      FPbScene.Canvas.Ellipse(50, 50, 150, 150);
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: What happens when you turn on Form.DoubleBuffered but NOT the panel double buffered property?  Try turning off any XP themes or aero glass, (go back to windows classic mode). Is there still flicker?

Comment: @Warren P: Thank you for very much your comment! By turning on Form.DoubleBuffered but off Panel.DoubleBuffered, the flicker on the right edge indeed goes away! (But the flicker of the PaintBox itself becomes more serious.) I feels that there probably is some best practice that I should follow?

Comment: If you get rid of the panel and put the TPaintBox directly on the form the flicker goes away? In that case, what you need is probably a modified panel control (subclass the TPanel and change it's paint and intercept WM_ERASEBACKGROUND in it).

Comment: @Warren P: Thank you very much for your help! Using exactly the above sample codes, if I comment out the container panel for paintbox, the flicker exists. But the flicker is between repainting form's background and paintbox's content. Before, it is random flicker showing the color of the paintbox's container panel.

Comment: @Warren P: Thank you for your recommendation. I am sorry but actually I have no idea how to incercept WM_ERASEBKGND correctly. I am not sure whether I should ask a separate question. Probably I should first post here a sample code showing my failure to intercept the panel's painting background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual technique is to play with form.DoubleBuffered, which I see you are already doing in code, so if it was that easy, I would think you would have solved it already.

I think one could also perhaps avoid any operation in the OnPaint other than a stretch-draw directly onto your paintbox.Canvas, from your offscreen bitmap. Anything else in OnPaint is a potentially flicker-inducing mistake.  That means, no modification of the TBitmap from within the OnPaint.  Let me say that a third time; Don't change state in paint events. Paint events should contain a "bitmap-blit" operation, GDI rectangle and line calls, etc, but nothing else.

I hesitate to recommend to anyone that they experiment with WM_SETREDRAW, but it is one technique people use. You can catch the move/resize window events or messages, and turn WM_SETREDRAW on/off, but this is SO fraught with complications and problems, that I don't recommend it. You can also call various Win32 functions to lock a window, and these are all highly dangerous and not recommended.

Comment: P: Thank you very much for your helpful suggestions! Form.DoubleBuffered=true seems not to work very well when there are panels in it. Or if it is feasible then I must have missed the best/common practice ? A second reason that I turned off the built in double buffering is performance. Either using OpenGl or using Graphics32 or using a off-screen bitmap, the double-buffer is already done once. Enabling Form or Panel's DoubleBuffer really slows some real-time application. I will try to read what you have recommended! Thank you!

Comment: P: You emphasize that there should be no modification of the offscreen TBitmap from within OnPaint. However, it is OnPaint that I am warned by system that I should refresh/redraw, or not? (I feel I lack basic logic here.) Furthermore, you mention I should not change state in paint events. Could you help to comment what state I should not change? I mean, states such as color, pen/brush properties are often subject to changes.

Comment: You should not be thinking that drawing on a bitmap and drawing to the paintbox canvas have to be done at the same time, as you currently are confused.  You should draw the bitmap once, when the content it depends on changes, only.  And then you should draw the bitmap onto the canvas inside the event. Is that clear?  A bitmap transfer onto the paintbox is very fast indeed.  In fact, if all you need is a bitmap, why don't you just use a TImage?

Comment: Here are things you should do in paint events: Write to or call any function under Paintbox.Canvas. Anything else you access should be read-only operations (no state changes, side effects) and must be VERY VERY FAST.  Avoid any function/procedure calls that take a long time to process.   One very common source of flicker is making a lot of function calls that are very slow while you redraw your paintbox.

Comment: P: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I will then try to learn about this best practices!

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the following is flicker-free for me:

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, Dialogs;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPnlCtrl, FPnlScene: TPanel;
    FPbScene: TPaintBox;
    procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Color := clYellow;

  FPnlCtrl := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FPnlCtrl.Parent := Self;
  FPnlCtrl.Align := alTop;
  FPnlCtrl.Color := clPurple;

  FPnlScene := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FPnlScene.Parent := Self;
  FPnlScene.Align := alClient;
  FPnlScene.Color := clBlue;

  FPbScene := TPaintBox.Create(Self);
  FPbScene.Parent := FPnlScene;
  FPbScene.Align := alClient;
  FPbScene.Color := clRed;

  FPbScene.OnPaint := Self.OnScenePaint;
end;

procedure TMainForm.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPbScene.Canvas.FillRect(FPbScene.ClientRect);
  FPbScene.Canvas.Ellipse(50, 50, 150, 150);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you for your time! But how come? Is it a form with a yellow panel on top and a red paintbox on bottom that you see? When the form is, for example, resized, the flickering is observable.

Comment: that's what I see. No flicker.

Comment: @David: I am sorry but I don't know what happens. In your modified code, values of properties such as ParentBackground, ParentColor, FullRepaint will be dependent on Delphi version. I would expect either the panels have their own background so that we would see a purple panel on top and a red paintbox on bottem, and a **less observable** flickering when resizing, or we would see a yellow panel on top and a red paintbox on bottom, but a **more severe** flickering. The former will have less flickering but I would think it is still observable.

Comment: @David: Thank you for your time! Could you help to upload your compiled binary so that I could download and see what it looks? I could not get flicker-free app using the above code but I probably miss something here.

Comment: @Xichen Li:  Did you try my suggestion of changing to windows classic theme?

Comment: @Warren P: I am using a Windows 7 Home and the theme is windows classic (i.e., no Aero effects).

Comment: @Warren P: Just know why you tell me to try use Windows Classic. Thanks again! https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=229495 The last post mentions "DwmCompositionEnabled", which is enabled when Windows Aero is used.