# Flicker in Gradient panel

Tags: delphi, gradient, tpanel

I have inherited a control from TPanel and in the Paint event handler, I have drawn the entire client rect using a gradient. This works perfectly fine until the user resizes.
When the panel is resized, the panel component flickers too much.

How can i avoid this flicker. I saw the gradients in MS office 2007, even if we resize the client area, there will not be a flicker. Please enlighten me on this.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi 2010 Control Flickering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142954/delphi-2010-control-flickering)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. TPanel has no OnPaint event. Please show us your code.

Comment: @NGLN, the control was derived from TPanel. An example is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813693/how-to-draw-on-a-tpanel

Comment: just a thought but is the panel set to DoubleBuffered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at this question [How to eliminate the flicker on the right edge of TPaintBox (for example when resizing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186729/how-to-eliminate-the-flicker-on-the-right-edge-of-tpaintbox-for-example-when-res)

Good overview of options to avoid flicker and also for TPanel.

Edit :
I made a quick test in my Delphi XE version on windows 7.

With this code I cannot reproduce any flicker.
The inherited Paint is removed and the Paint routine is quite fast.

If you still can see flicker, the proposal from Simon can be implemented, but better keep the bitmap created for the lifetime of the component itself.

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TGradientPanel = class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sPanel : TGradientPanel;
  public
    { Public declarations }
 end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses Math;

 procedure GradVertical(Canvas:TCanvas; Rect:TRect; FromColor, ToColor:TColor) ;
 var
   Y:integer;
   dr,dg,db:Extended;
   C1,C2:TColor;
   r1,r2,g1,g2,b1,b2:Byte;
   R,G,B:Byte;
   cnt:Integer;
 begin
    C1 := FromColor;
    R1 := GetRValue(C1) ;
    G1 := GetGValue(C1) ;
    B1 := GetBValue(C1) ;

    C2 := ToColor;
    R2 := GetRValue(C2) ;
    G2 := GetGValue(C2) ;
    B2 := GetBValue(C2) ;

    dr := (R2-R1) / Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top;
    dg := (G2-G1) / Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top;
    db := (B2-B1) / Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top;

    cnt := 0;
    for Y := Rect.Top to Rect.Bottom-1 do
    begin
       R := R1+Ceil(dr*cnt) ;
       G := G1+Ceil(dg*cnt) ;
       B := B1+Ceil(db*cnt) ;

       Canvas.Pen.Color := RGB(R,G,B) ;
       Canvas.MoveTo(Rect.Left,Y) ;
       Canvas.LineTo(Rect.Right,Y) ;
       Inc(cnt) ;
    end;
 end;


constructor TGradientPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Self.ParentBackground := FALSE;
end;

procedure TGradientPanel.Paint;
var
  rect : TRect;
begin
  //inherited;  // Avoid any inherited paint actions as they may clear the panel background
  rect := GetClientRect;
  GradVertical( Self.Canvas, rect, clBlue, clRed);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sPanel := TGradientPanel.Create( Self);
  sPanel.Parent := Self;
  sPanel.Top := 10;
  sPanel.Left := 10;
  sPanel.Width := 300;
  sPanel.Height := 300;
  sPanel.Anchors := [akLeft,akRight,akTop,akBottom];
  sPanel.Enabled := TRUE;
  sPanel.Visible := TRUE;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should have been a comment to the original question. :)

Comment: @Ken, Ok I added a bit more input to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

A way to reduce flicker is to draw the gradient to a temporary bitmap the draw the entire contents of the bitmap to the panel. This method assumes you have an OnPaint method and a canvas to draw on in your inherited panel.

So something like this (untested)

```
var bmp : Tbitmap;

procedure AfterConstruction;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
end;

procedure Destroy()
begin
  if Assigned(bmp) then FreeandNil(bmp);
end;

//redraw you bmp gradient
procedure Panel1.OnResize();
begin
  if Assigned(bmp) then //ensure the bmp s created in your constructor
  begin
  try
    bmp.SetBounds(Panel1.Clientrect); //ensure the bmp is the same size as the panel
    //draw your gradient on the bmp
    Panel1.OnPaint();//repaint the tpanel

  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

//paint to the panel
procedure Panel1.OnPaint()
begin
  Panel1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmp); //use the OnPaint method to draw to the canvas
end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: surely the DoubleBuffered property does that for you?

Comment: Setting ParentBackground to false has solved the flickering issue. Thank you guys for providing good inputs.